# converting/Casting ISingleResult - List values to DataTable without Looping

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I am using **Linq to Sql**. When My **StoredProcedure** Executing its result ll returned in form of **IMultipleResults**.

I am converting it to **ISingleResults** and It can be **Casted as List**.

So I need to **Convert it to DataTable** so That I can **Bind it to Dataset** and **Pass the values to UI.**

But I want such method where I can **convert it without LOOP**.

Please Any body Help me.

For Any Clarification Contact me.

Thanking you.

Comment: Just wondering why your datalayer is using stored procedures, your business logic is using linq and your UI is using datasets. Perhaps you could consider using your linq objects in the UI? You can bind a List to a datagrid just as easily as a dataset. It just seems like an awfull lot of conversions to me.

Comment: I am using storedprocedure to retrieve data and i need dataset to bind it to my datasource. So If you know something then help me and post ur solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you might want to see if you could cast your list to a BindingList, or do something like this:

```
BindingListX = New BindingList(Of elementX)(QueryResult.ToList())
```

You might be able to bind with that.  If that doesn't work though here's another question:  Do you want to not use a loop in your code at all, or just not see a loop in your code?  It is possible to create an extension function that does the conversion:

```
public static class HelperFunctions
    {
        public static void Map<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> func)
        {
            foreach (T i in source)
                func(i);
        }

        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(properties.Select(x => new DataColumn(x.Name, x.PropertyType)).ToArray());
            source.Select(x => dt.NewRow().ItemArray = properties.Select(y => y.GetValue(x, null)).ToArray()).Map(x => dt.Rows.Add(x));
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

But as you can see, the other extension function 'Map' is nothing more than a foreach that can be used inline.  If that is not what you want then I apologize and will try to come up with a different way.

It is also worth noting that I'm not sure if assigning to Item Array is the best way to populate a row so if it doesn't work then please let me know so that I may draft another version of the function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sir I am not getting code can you plz make it simple and I dont want to use any loop in my code so plz try to do it.